# Tape recorder with live chassis

Tags: voltage, transformer

[image]I am trying to repair a Revox B77. The issue is that the whole machine is live. I am looking to know if the issue is with the voltage selector or even some guidance as a starting place where to look in order to make it safe. The machine works fine but is obviously dangerous. Any help as a starting point would be gratefully appreciated.
I have made a video and strung together what i can showing the machine [Revox video](https://youtu.be/S5CxgGSR8z8)

Comment: what does this mean exactly? `whole machine is live` ...... start with your power outlet .... make sure that it is not mis-wired ....... what happens if you reverse the power plug?

Comment: This could do with some more debugging details including a schematic, if available.

Comment: Welcome to EESE. However repair and usage questions can be considered off-topic in this site unless some reasonable understanding of the problem and effort to solve it are shown in the question itself. Edit your question to add information in that regard.

Comment: I reversed the polarity and now i only have 18v on the chassis. I will rewire the inlet and live with 18v. Thank you very much for that jsotola

Comment: 18V is likely still too much.  The power cable for this device should be polarised and you should check the wiring of the cord end if possible, the plug you're plugging in to if a different plug causes a different result, and what's going on.  I watched as long as I could, but your video is horrible, so you should likely take a new video (or just well lit and focused pictures of the relevant parts).

Comment: For this to happen in the first place, either the device is ungrounded (bad if metal chassis) or you have a broken ground somewhere between it and your panel.  As Jsotola suggests, you have line and neutral reversed somewhere between your panel and the device as well, but it is *important* not to permanently solve this sort of problem by simply switching conductors.  You must figure out specifically whether it is the device or the receptacle that is miswired (likely the device, but *be sure*) and fix that problem.

Comment: Thanks K H, will have a look at that. i have the wiring diagram on the video at the end. (I've added it to question at top).As you can see the selector creates loops between connections when turned. Can i cut away the irrelevant cables and the whole voltage selector and just leave the two cables for 240v (Ireland)?

Comment: As I read the schematic, nothing on the primary of the transformer should be connected to the case, chassis, or the rest of the circuit.  Perhaps there is a short from a primary winding or AC input wiring to the case.

Answer (score 1):

That machine should absolutely NOT be live chassis, they were typically double insulated to avoid earth loops with the (typically grounded) hifi amps they were used with, but if there is significant current to chassis you need to find it and fix it.

I would note that given a high impedance meter you can sometimes measure a fair voltage to chassis even with no real fault due to the coupling to the interwinding screen, so it is worth using an old school meter of the 20k/Volt sort rather then the modern DMM with Mohm input when checking this.

Answer (score 0):

The wiring in that video looks horrid.  There are blobs of solder close to the wires.  there are wires where the insulation has been scraped away.

I would start by unplugging it, setting the multimeter to continuity, and start poking around to see which bit of the wiring is actually shorting to ground.  Look carefully for things that are shorted out.

Given that the tape recorder has a metal chassis, is there any good reason why it isn't earthed via a 3-pin plug?